# Unity UNET - calling [Command] outside of player object

Tags: unity-game-engine, network-programming, unity-networking

So I understand that [command] does not work on non-player objects, however ...why? how am I supposed to sync data of non-player objects, such as NPC locations.  The ability to call Command on non-player objects would save a lot of repeated computation time on each client.

Has anyone come up with a workaround to this design decision?

Also, it seems that SyncVars aren't being synced if not on player objects as-well.

Right now my best strategy is to store a whoooole lot of data on the player objects and have to keep making references to it from outer classes

EDIT:
OOps my mistake, as pointed out SyncVars are working on non-player objects, just only when updated on the server

Comment: FYI, as of 5.2 which came out this month. you can now call Command outside of player objects.  YIIPEE!!!!

Comment: where is that code? i am using 5.4 but non player command function not executing on server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, *[Command]* is for sending player RPC's to server.

However, *SyncVars* will sync the state from server to client on any object with a **NetworkBehaviour** (not just a player object).

The authoritative server approach is to have the server spawn your NPC locations with `NetworkServer.Spawn()` and then update the NPC *Syncvars*, and they automatically will update on all clients.

If you really need to send a *[Command]* from a client, with new versions of Unity you can grant a scene object local player authority using `AssignClientAuthority()`:

If you have a PRO license and can access the Unity 5.2 beta builds then they added this in 5.2b1

> **Networking**: Added support for client-side authority for non-player
>   objects. The new function
>   `NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority(GameObject obj, NetworkConnection conn)` allows authority to be assigned to a client by
>   its connection when an object is created. This would typically be used
>   in a command handler for a client asking to spawn an object, then the
>   client's connection would be passed in. For example:
>
> ```
> [Command] 
> void CmdSpawn() { 
>     var go = (GameObject)Instantiate(otherPrefab,
>     transform.position + new Vector3(0,1,0), Quaternion.identity);
>     NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority(go, base.connectionToClient); 
> }
> ```
>
> For setting the authority on objects after they are created, there are
>   the new functions `AssignClientAuthority(NetworkConnection conn)` and
>   `RemoveClientAuthority(NetworkConnection conn)` on the **NetworkIdentity**
>   class. Note that only one client can be the authority for an object at
>   a time. On the client that has authority, the function
>   `OnStartAuthority()` is called, and the property **hasAuthority** will be
>   true. The set of objects that is owned by a client is available in the
>   new property **NetworkConnection.clientOwnedObjects** which is a set of
>   **NetworkInstanceIds**. This set can be used on the server when a message
>   is received to ensure that the client that sent the message actually
>   owns the object. When a client disconnects, the function
>   `DestroyPlayersForConnection` now destroys all the objects owned by that
>   connection, not just the player object. Objects which have their
>   authority set to a client must have **LocalPlayerAuthority** set in their
>   **NetworkIdentity**. Previously only player objects could have local
>   authority, which meant that the **NetworkTransform** (and other
>   components) could only be used for controlling the single player
>   object for a connection on a client. With these changes it is possible
>   to have multiple objects on a client that are locally controlled.