# UNET Client Cant Send Server Commands, Host Can

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming, unity-networking

So as the title suggests, I'm having a problem where commands being sent by the client are not triggered.

The basic functionality I'm trying to get working is that when an enemy is in front of the player and I click, that player will be momentarily stunned. Works fine if I'm host, and both sides perfectly register.

If I'm playing as client, I get to the point where the command "should" be sent, but I notice I get a warning that says "Trying to send command for non-local player". As well, nothing happens on either end. Obviously I must be doing something wrong client side, but have no idea what other way to go about this.

The "problem" code.

```
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) {
            Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
            RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
            Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 20f);
            if (hit.transform != null) {
                if (hit.rigidbody != null) {
                    PlayerController controller = hit.rigidbody.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
                    if (controller != null) {
                        if (!controller.stunned) {
                            // Send the stun command to the server
                            controller.CmdStun();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The method calls

```
[Command]
public void CmdStun() {
    // Report that the stun was sent
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Stun Sent");
    RpcStun();
}

[ClientRpc]
public void RpcStun() {
    // Activate the stun timer.
    stunTimer.Start();
    // Track the players original color.
    normalColor = manager.color;
    // Make the players bot look like its shut down.
    manager.InitiateColorChange(Color.black);
    // Other code will check against this before trying to send another stun command.
    stunned = true;
}
```

Edit:
Upon request heres the two scripts in their entirety.

http://pastebin.com/mr4A9ZgH

http://pastebin.com/Qg0AjCCD

Player configuration in unity:

https://gyazo.com/400c5b3a95c1a58f9b6e930b0c3c853b

https://gyazo.com/c17a7317767a00e2150ff34b03a03e8f

https://gyazo.com/322731aefbe69f9567d2b395523b8f2a

Full Warning Message

> Trying to send command for non-local player.
>   UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkBehaviour:SendCommandInternal(NetworkWriter,
>   Int32, String) PlayerController:CallCmdStun()
>   ObjectInteractor:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/ObjectInteractor.cs:58)

Comment: So, when playing as a remote client, you don't see the Stun Sent in the console?

Comment: If the host sends the command, both host and the client get the log. If the client sends the command, nothing happens on either end.

Comment: Is it possible to post more about your setup? With many required parts in UNET spread out over game objects and code, it can be difficult to troubleshoot without the whole picture.

Comment: Added some pastebin links with the full classes.

Comment: Are there other instances of Commands not working from a remote client? Did you check that you have the cloud project id entered into Unity's settings?

Comment: I'm using localhost. Presently, this is the first command I'm trying to get working.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please try registering your project with Unity at https://multiplayer.unity3d.com, and then entering the cloud project id in the Unity settings.

Comment: That made the online matchmaking feature work, still the same problem though.

Comment: Are you using the latest patch release? UNET has had its share of bugs (and fixes).

Comment: I'm using Unity 5.1.1f1

Comment: Always upgrade to the latest patch when working with UNET. https://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases

Comment: Updated to the latest patch. Unfortunately the problem is still there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88825/discussion-between-user3071284-and-sebastian-thomas-edward-lawe).

Answer (score 2):

You must assign script to the root of the OBJECT. I was Having same problem. There are few constrains you must consider.

1. A NetworkIdentity must be on the root game object of a spawnable prefab
2. NetworkBehaviour scripts must be on the same game object as the NetworkIdentity, not on child game objects
3. Prefabs can’t be registered with the NetworkManager unless they have a NetworkIdentity on their root object

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are calling a command on a `gameobject` you spawn by `networkserver` or the object has existed the scene already. Anyway, the object is not a `playerprefab` that you assign it in the `NetworkManager's SpawnInfo`.

So, for those Object that `'Trying to send command for non-local player'`. You need to give their `NetworkIdentity` a `'Authority'` which enable them to call `[Command]`.And to give them 'Authority' you should use

```
NetworkIdentity.AssignClientAuthority(connectionToClient).
```

And, as a fact `NetworkIdentity.AssignClientAuthority` may only call on a server. You need an other `[Command]` on `'Player'` to `'AssignClientAuthority'`.

More details are here：

[Unity UNET - calling [Command] outside of player object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666024/unity-unet-calling-command-outside-of-player-object)

(I'm a Chinese, so maybe I didn't express myslef clearly, hope you can understand.)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have a NetworkIdentity component, with Local Player Authority checked, on your player prefab. Then above the problem code, only run it if it's the local player by adding the following:

```
if (!isLocalPlayer)
    return;
```

**EDIT:** Be sure to include the UPID (from registering your project at https://multiplayer.unity3d.com) in Unity's Player settings (Edit -> Project Settings -> Player) in the Cloud Project Id field if you're testing remote clients. Even if you're using localhost, the remote client uses Unity's relay server to connect to your host game.

**EDIT 2:** Try changing the call to `controller.CmdStun()` to `controller.Stun()`. Then in `PlayerController` add a public function `Stun()` that calls private function `CmdStun()`.

Comment: I should have metioned that this check already happens before this code block. As well, eveything is already properly configured. Problem is, my code works host to client, but not client to host for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

As you said:

> warning that says "Trying to send command for non-local player".

You can send commands from non-player objects as [unity docs stated](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActions.html):

> Commands are sent from player objects on the client to player objects
>   on the server. For security, Commands can only be sent from YOUR
>   player object, so you cannot control the objects of other players.

**BUT**

> Starting with Unity release 5.2 it is possible to send commands from
>   non-player objects that have client authority. These objects must have
>   been spawned with NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority or have
>   authority set with NetworkIdentity.AssignClientAuthority. Commands
>   sent from these object are run on the server instance of the object,
>   not on the associated player object for the client.